# Filtering some dates when they are of type string, relative to the user's locale

Tags: javascript

So I'm getting some dates from my backend.

I only need the date (without the time) and the format should be relative to the user's browser settings.

I've chosen this approach:

```
function dateFormatter(params) {
    if (!params.value || params.value == 'None') return ''
    return new Date(params.value).toLocaleString(undefined, options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: '2-digit' });
}
```

So far so good. It is working fine. Passing undefined as the first parameter makes it take whatever locale the user's using.

The problem is that now, for those strings returned by this function, I need a comparator. Something like this:

```
filterParams: {
            // provide comparator function
            comparator: (filterLocalDateAtMidnight, cellValue) => {
                const dateAsString = cellValue;

                if (dateAsString == null) {
                    return 0;
                }

                // In the example application, dates are stored as dd/mm/yyyy
                // We create a Date object for comparison against the filter date
                const dateParts = dateAsString.split('/');
                const day = Number(dateParts[2]);
                const month = Number(dateParts[1]) - 1;
                const year = Number(dateParts[0]);
                const cellDate = new Date(year, month, day);

                // Now that both parameters are Date objects, we can compare
                if (cellDate < filterLocalDateAtMidnight) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (cellDate > filterLocalDateAtMidnight) {
                    return 1;
                }
                return 0;
            }
```

How can I implement this comparator? Because my date format is dynamic according to the user, I can't just split dateParts[] like this example does.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your code if  dates are stored as `dd/mm/yyyy` you use `day = Number(dateParts[2])` and not `day = Number(dateParts[0])` ?

Comment: You should keep the original data you receive from your backend and do all sorting, filtering etc operations on that, it's the ground truth. Use your formatting function only when displaying the results in the UI.

Comment: @MisterJojo that code is an example from the docs of the framework I'm using. It doesn't matter. I have to implement a function similar to JS's compareTo, that was the ideea

Comment: @Etheryte I don't really know if that's possible, to be honest. I'm using ag-grid with VueJS, I think this is the way it works.

Comment: You need to define a renderer for the cells, you'll find more information in the docs.